# Divide and conquer trominos algorithm in C

Tags: c, algorithm

This is the classic [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) problem. We have a **2^n * 2^n** board and we want to fill it with L shaped cubes. We know there is one block on the board that we can't assign a cube. This problem is also known as [tromino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino) problem (somewhat).

### Problem

My solution works for n = 1 and n = 2. But when I wan to further generalize the solution (n > 2), I don't get all the blocks filled and some of them consist of false L shaped cube parts.

### Program structure

### Inputs

The user enters `n` and the position of the missing cube `t` on the board.

### Output

We print the board filled with "trominos". We assign a value to each one of them. The missing cude always get zero value and each "tromino" contains a integer value (1, 2, 3, ....).

### Solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void recursiveSolve(int m, int A[m][m], int A_row, int A_col, int t_row, int t_y, int currBlockNum, int boardSize);

int main(void) {
    int n, m;

    do {
        printf("Give n > 0: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n <= 0);

    m = pow(2, n);

    int A[m][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            A[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    int t_row, t_col;

    do {
        printf("Give missing square row coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &t_row);
        printf("Give missing square column coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &t_col);
    } while (t_row >= m || t_col >= m);

    A[t_row][t_col] = 0;

    recursiveSolve(m, A, 0, 0, t_row, t_col, 1, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                printf("%2d ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void recursiveSolve(int m, int A[m][m], int A_row, int A_col, int t_row, int t_col, int currBlockNum, int boardSize) {
    if (boardSize == 2) { // fill with L shaped block the area that is blank (no block exist).

        // check first which part of our board if filled up with  a block
        // and then paint the other.
        if (A[A_row][A_col] != -1) { // block exist at the top-left corner
            A[A_row+1][A_col]  = currBlockNum; // paint the bottom-left corner
            A[A_row+1][A_col+1] = currBlockNum; // paint the bottom-right corner
            A[A_row][A_col+1] = currBlockNum; // paint the top-right corner

        } else if (A[A_row][A_col+1] != -1) { // block exist at the top-right corner
            A[A_row][A_col] = currBlockNum; // paint the top-left corner
            A[A_row+1][A_col] = currBlockNum; // paint the bottom-left corner
            A[A_row+1][A_col+1] = currBlockNum; // paint the bottom-right corner

        } else if (A[A_row+1][A_col] != -1) { // block exist at the bottom-left corner
            A[A_row][A_col] = currBlockNum;
            A[A_row][A_col+1] = currBlockNum;
            A[A_row+1][A_col+1] = currBlockNum;

        } else { // block exist at the bottom-right corner
            A[A_row][A_col] = currBlockNum;
            A[A_row][A_col+1] = currBlockNum;
            A[A_row+1][A_col] = currBlockNum;
        }

    } else {
        int A_halfSize = boardSize / 2;

        // the bellow calculations allow us to check which
        // sub-partition of our board includes the missing block,
        // as well as how we should paint the center L shaped block.
        int A_rowCenter = A_row + A_halfSize;
        int A_colCenter = A_col + A_halfSize;


        if (t_row < A_rowCenter) { // missing block in top half
            if (t_col < A_colCenter ) { // missing block is in top left half
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
            } else { // missing block is in top right half
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
            }

        } else { // missing block in bottom half
            if (t_col < A_colCenter ) { // missing block is in bottom left half
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
            } else { // missing block is in bottom right half
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
            }
        }

        // solve each sub-partion recursively

        // top-right sub-partion
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_row, A_colCenter, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);

        // bottom-right sub-partion
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_rowCenter, A_colCenter, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);

        // bottom left sub-partition
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_rowCenter, A_col, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);

        // top-left sub-partition
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_row, A_col, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, the strategy is to place the L in such a way that it occupies exactly one cube in the 3 squares that doesn't contain an already occupied cube.

In other words:

- you split the input square into 4 squares.
- One of these already have an occupied cube.
- You place the L so that the 3 other squares also ends up with exactly one occupied cube.

Consequently you now have 4 squares - all with exactly one occupied cube. So now you can run the function on these four squares.

[image]

Now you can handle each of the 4 squares independently as each square has exactly one occupied cube.

**So what is the problem with your code?**

The problem is that you don't update the position of the occupied cube but simply keeps the original position.

```
    // top-right sub-partion
    recursiveSolve(m, A, A_row, A_colCenter, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                             May need update before calling

    // bottom-right sub-partion
    recursiveSolve(m, A, A_rowCenter, A_colCenter, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                    May need update before calling

    // bottom left sub-partition
    recursiveSolve(m, A, A_rowCenter, A_col, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                             May need update before calling

    // top-left sub-partition
    recursiveSolve(m, A, A_row, A_col, t_row, t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                        May need update before calling
```

**For 3 of the 4 calls, you need to update the position of the occupied square.**

That can be achieved in many ways. Here is one approach:

```
void recursiveSolve(int m, int A[m][m], int A_row, int A_col, int t_row, int t_col, int currBlockNum, int boardSize) {
    if (boardSize == 2) {

        // Keep your existing code unchanged here

    } else {
        int A_halfSize = boardSize / 2;

        // the bellow calculations allow us to check which
        // sub-partition of our board includes the missing block,
        // as well as how we should paint the center L shaped block.
        int A_rowCenter = A_row + A_halfSize;
        int A_colCenter = A_col + A_halfSize;

        // Calculate the position of the center cubes
        // as these will be the new occupied cub for
        // 3 of the 4 squares
        int TR_t_row = A_rowCenter - 1;
        int TR_t_col = A_colCenter;

        int BR_t_row = A_rowCenter;
        int BR_t_col = A_colCenter - 1;

        int BL_t_row = A_rowCenter - 1;
        int BL_t_col = A_colCenter;

        int TL_t_row = A_rowCenter - 1;
        int TL_t_col = A_colCenter - 1;



        if (t_row < A_rowCenter) { // missing block in top half
            if (t_col < A_colCenter ) { // missing block is in top left half
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;

                TL_t_row = t_row;  // Roll back to 
                TL_t_col = t_col;  // original occupied cube

            } else { // missing block is in top right half
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;

                TR_t_row = t_row;  // Roll back
                TR_t_col = t_col;

            }

        } else { // missing block in bottom half
            if (t_col < A_colCenter ) { // missing block is in bottom left half
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;

                BL_t_row = t_row;  // Roll back
                BL_t_col = t_col;

            } else { // missing block is in bottom right half
                A[A_rowCenter][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter-1] = currBlockNum;
                A[A_rowCenter-1][A_colCenter] = currBlockNum;

                BR_t_row = t_row;  // Roll back
                BR_t_col = t_col;

            }
        }

        // solve each sub-partion recursively

        // Use the 8 new variables for the recursive calls

        // top-right sub-partion
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_row, A_colCenter, TR_t_row, TR_t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                             //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        // bottom-right sub-partion
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_rowCenter, A_colCenter, BR_t_row, BR_t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                                   //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        // bottom left sub-partition
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_rowCenter, A_col, BL_t_row, BL_t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                             //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        // top-left sub-partition
        recursiveSolve(m, A, A_row, A_col, TL_t_row, TL_t_col, ++currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
                                       //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

### Update

If you want to avoid using the same number for multiple L, you should pass a pointer to `currBlockNum` instead.

Change the prototype - notice the `int* currBlockNum`:

```
void recursiveSolve(int m, int A[m][m], int A_row, int A_col, int t_row, int t_y, int* currBlockNum, int boardSize);
```

In main do:

```
int currBlockNum = 1;
recursiveSolve(m, A, 0, 0, t_row, t_col, &currBlockNum, m);
                                        ^^^
                                        Notice
```

In the function change **all** place where you want to assign the value - like

```
A[A_row+1][A_col]  = *currBlockNum;
                    ^^^
                    Notice
```

and **every time** you call the function recursively, do an increment first - like:

```
    ++(*currBlockNum);
    recursiveSolve(m, A, A_row, A_colCenter, TR_t_row, TR_t_col, currBlockNum, A_halfSize);
```

Comment: okay I though it too, but is it possible based on my code? I don't want to change the structure now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood the problem. I just can't find the right combinations to make with the missing cube position.

Comment: I made a  progress I believe. Please check my update. Thank you very much!!! Ohh just saw we thought the same thing!

Comment: please update your answer to clarify this. You have to add `++(*currBlockNum);` above all the four recursions!

Comment: @GeorgeGkas - I have made that part a little more clear